# Image as cover page

Tags: graphics, covers

I want to add a figure to fill the whole first page (instead of making it with the latex commands). And then to add *a blank page* to begin the next chapter on an odd page number. When I write :

```
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[heigth=24cm]{images\pagedegarde.pdf}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\strut
\newpage
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Remerciements}
...
```

instead of having juste one blank page after the figure, I have *one before the cover page, and one after the cover page*.
If I add the H option, I have *two blank pages* after the figure.
What shall I do? Thank you ;)

Comment: Does adding a `\clearpage` after the figure solve your problem ? If your cover page is a pdf file, perhaps you could consider including it with the package `pdfpages`.

Comment: Using `figure` for this purpose is wrong. Either use `center` or, better, the commands provided by `pdfpages`.

Comment: in fact, I use the document class *book* and I would like to keep it. In this case, clearpage won't work to have just one blank page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you satisfied with including the image your way?
If you want to use the formatting (esp. the margins) of your pdf-file consider the use of `\includepdf` from [pdfpages](ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)

`\cleardoublepage` lets you start on the next odd page number

This way it works:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf{test.pdf}
\cleardoublepage
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Remerciements}
\end{document}
```

Btw: There's no need to set page counter. `\frontmatter` will start with 'i' in default.

Comment: In fact, it seems that just by removing the `\setcounter{page}{0}` line, it works. I can not figure why, but anyway, it works. Thanx for your tips!